# Chalice deploy for S3 event throwing an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chalice

The `s3-event` source project throwing an error while deploying

```
chalice new-project
s3-event-source

chalice deploy
```

Error:

```
chalice.deploy.deployer.ChaliceDeploymentError: ERROR - While deploying your chalice application, received the following error:

 An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the 
 PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: The notification destination 
 service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy the chalice app to the same region you created the s3 bucket.

If your s3 bucket is in Ireland (eu-west-1) run in your CLI:

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
```

Change the region accordingly to your s3 bucket.